# Каким образом делать такое подчеркивание?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как делать подчеркивание такого рода? Есть две идеи, это `SVG` и просто `PNG` картинка с абсолютным позиционированием относительно блока с заголовком. Может есть способы с помощью чистого `CSS`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Самое простое решение - это svg*

```css
svg {
width:347;
height:188;
background:#3D4248;
}
 #txt {
font-size:70px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 fill:white;
}
svg path {
fill:none;
stroke:white;
stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="347" height="188" viewBox="0 0 347 188" >  


<text id="txt" x="70" y="120" >Expire</text>
 <path d="m74.9 149.5 97.2 0 5.3 5.7 96.8 0-0.4 0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение на `CSS`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3D4248;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 34px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #3D4248;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper .line::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.7px;
  left: -1.8px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrapper span {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.wrapper span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 91px;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <span>Expire</span>
</div>
```